# Какую лицензию выбрать, чтобы моё приложение не использовали в коммерческих целях?

Tags: github, лицензирование

Создал веб-приложение для тренировки японского языка. Загрузил на gihub.pages.

Не хочу, чтобы моё приложение использовали в коммерческих целях, какую лицензию выбрать?

Если там все лицензии разрешают коммерческое использование, то есть какая нибудь лицензия, которая дает мне отчисления? Или хотя бы та, в которой меня упомянут как автора или типа того?

Comment: Мне кажется давным давно все прошаренные в OpenSource перешли на другой вид заработка, т.к. любой может спокойно взять исходники, приправить своим соусом и использовать у себя и разраб никогда в жизни об этом не узнает

Comment: Да не открывай ты исходный код тогда. Если бы мне очень хотелось то я бы опубликовал под GPL, он не запрещает коммерческое использование, только обязывает отдавать исходный код по требованию клиента который использует продукт., а этого коммерческие компании не любят. Общепринятой лицензии под твое описание я не знаю, но бывает софт публикуются подо такими лицензиями, если я не ошибаюсь тот же QNX 20 лет назад тоже публиковал исходники но это был не открытый софт.

Comment: Судя по вашему описанию - freeware, использование и бесплатное распространение по умолчанию в лицензии, при этом коммерческое - можно запретить. (а можно не запрещать)